# Error (The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.)

Tags: sql-server, sql, vb6

Estoy trabajando con pago con tarjeta .. en una de las tiendas (proyectos) funcionan pero solo en 2 cajas marca este problema

para insertar ya los datos es esta secuencia

```
INSERT INTO TransaccionesPINPAD  (CodigoSucursal, IdTransaccion, Usuario, FechaCreacion, FechaTransaccion, MODE, CMD_TRANS, 
MERCHANT_ID, TERMINAL_ID,  CONTROL_NUMBER, AMOUNT, PAYW_RESULT, CHIP_DECLINED, AUTH_CODE, EMV_TAGS, CodigoTicket, CARD_NUMBER, 
CuentaCliente,AUTH_RESULT,PAYW_CODE,MensajeDeError,TEXT,CUST_REQ_DATE,AUTH_REQ_DATE,AUTH_RSP_DATE,CUST_RSP_DATE,EMV_DATA,
ReferenciaAnterior,Cancelacion,Impresora)  VALUES ('A',2,'IPCAJA2','16/10/2019 15:40:29','16/10/2019 15:40:29','PRD','AUTH',
'7233272','327777482','A-VNC-2','4.83','','0','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','0','BIXOLON SRP-350plus')  
16/10/2019 15:40:31"
```

> "Error -2147217913 (The conversion of a varchar data type to a
>   datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.) 
>       in procedure TxtPago_KeyDown of Formulario Frm_PVSUPAGO2 16/10/2019 15:40:34"

intente agregar con el addtime pero tomo la fecha desde el proyecto en vb6, anteriormente marcaba este error

> "Error 0 () in procedure TxtPago_KeyDown of Formulario Frm_PVSUPAGO2
>   16/10/2019 03:33:31 p.m.

cambie el formato de la fecha pero ahora me salio el error actual

Answer (score 1):

Hola supongo que el error es porque tienes definido un formato de fecha diferente en sql, cuando ingresas la fecha 16/10/2019 (dmy) en sql esta definido como (mdy) y por eso el error.

Con este comando puedes ver que formato de fecha tienes

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes poner Select GETDATE() para ver el formato de la fecha,

Por ejemplo el mio es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y yo tengo que poner

```
Insert into Tabla(Fecha) values('2019-10-16')
```

También puedes ver este tutorial para el formato de fecha

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://database.guide/how-to-change-the-current-date-format-in-sql-server-t-sql/)